# HASKELL *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse (possible duplicate)

Tags: parsing, haskell, parse-error

I have this code

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)

eval :: [Int] -> IO()
eval liste = do
    putStrLn "Please enter a positive integer or an operater ( + / - / * ): "
    input <- getLine
    let
        ord = words input
        cmd = read (head ord) :: Char
        in
            if isDigit cmd then
                let nyliste = (read [cmd] :: Int) : liste in do
                print nyliste
                eval nyliste
            else if isOperator cmd then if null liste || length liste == 1 then do
                    putStrLn "Invalid input! Start by adding at least two positive integers"
                    eval liste
                else let
                    fst = head liste
                    snd = head $ tail liste
                    in case cmd of
                        '+' -> let
                            newValue = fst + snd
                            oppliste = newValue : drop 2 liste
                            in do
                                print oppliste
                                eval oppliste
                        '-' -> let
                            newValue = fst - snd
                            oppliste = newValue : drop 2 liste
                            in do
                                print oppliste
                                eval oppliste
                        '*' -> let
                            newValue = fst * snd
                            oppliste = newValue : drop 2 liste
                            in do
                                print oppliste
                                eval oppliste
                        _ -> do
                            putStrLn "Invalid input! Start by adding at least two positive integers"
                            eval liste
            else do
                putStrLn "Invalid input! Start by adding at least two positive integers"
                eval liste


isOperator :: Char -> Bool
isOperator c = c == '*' || c == '+' || c == '-'

main :: IO()
main = eval []
```

Which, when I try to run it, it gives me this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci> main
Please enter a positive integer or an operater ( + / - / * ):
1
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
ghci>
```

I have looked at similar questions, and I understand that the error has something to do with my use of `read`, but I don't understand much more than that. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: With `read (..) :: Char` you're trying to parse a `Char`, and chars should be in single quotes, e.g. `'a'` or `'1'`. But your input doesn't have any quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head ord` is just `"1"`. For `read` to make that into a `Char`, it would have to be `"'1'"` instead. Since a `String` is just a `[Char]`, you can just take the first element to get what you want instead of bothering with `read` there at all.